# Регулярное выражение для получения атрибутов запроса

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, запрос

Вот код:

```js
var query = "id  INT    (10)  AUTO_INCREMENT  KEY,  name  VARCHAR( 255 ),  info  VARCHAR    ( 255)  DEFAULT('your text' )  DEFAULT('your text' ) AUTO_INCREMENT, text ,   age INT(2), date DATETIME DEFAULT(NOW()), counter INT(10) DEFAULT(10)".split(',');
var regular = /\w+([\s]*\((.*?)\)(\s|$)|(\s|$))/g;


for (var i = 0, matches; i < query.length; i++) {
  query[i] = query[i].trimLeft();

  matches = query[i].match(regular);

  console.log(query[i]);
  console.log(matches);
}
```

Как видно, я парсю `query` запрос на значения и атрибуты. Скорость парсинга должна быть большой, поэтому экономлю на спичках. Как оптимизировать регулярку?

Пример в живую: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZnjL/

Comment: А что, если запятая будет в DEFAULT ?

Comment: А это, я свою базу делаю :D Я бы с радостью убрал знак вопроса из выражения, но тогда опять надо мудрить. Может быть вообще DEFAULT'ы чанками заменить?

Comment: @lampa а может, если вы свою базу делаете, так ещё и под js, не нужно вообще интерфейса командного ? типа

    var fields={id: {type: 'int',length: 100},{text_value: {type: "text",default: "NO DATA"}};
    var table=db.createTable(fields,options); //options можно придумать самому

Comment: @eicto хе, это не кошерно, это задание новичкам ;D

Comment: чтож некошерного ? по моему как-раз некошерно в объектном языке делать обращение к базе через собственный парсер строк на этом языке написанном, да еще и используя регекспы :), зачем вам грабли с injection ?

Comment: @eicto вы пытаетесь меня переубедить?!) Я сам прекрасно понимаю, что данные передавать лучше не строкой, а объектом: удобнее, безопаснее, понятнее. Но тут, как говорится, "хочу и всё")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/546457/815386

типа невозможно использовать регулярные выражения для парсинга рекурсивных структур.

Comment: @eicto так я и говорю - привести к общему виду с помощью чанков и парсить.

Comment: фразы "скорость работы" и "регулярные выражения" плохо совместимы между собой.

Я бы писал нормальный парсер. Правда парсеров sql, доступных в открытом доступе мне не встречалось, только коммерческие и жутко дорогие.

Comment: 1. Рекурсивные структуры парсить можно.  
2. В языках вроде JavaScript регексами можно получить скорость больше, чем обычным парсингом.

Comment: А почему на js? У вас разбор бежит в браузере? Может, отдать получится отдать эту функциональность в кусок на более быстром языке?

По поводу ускорения: почему бы не повыбрасывать лишние пробелы «вручную» до разбора строки? Регулярка по идее упростится.

Comment: @ReinRaus мне действительно хотелось бы увидеть регулярку которая проходит [этот](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2ZnjL/4/) тест. (последнее выражение про split, можно не проходить)

Comment: Что делать с:  

    PRIMARY KEY
    NOT NULL
    и.т.п.
Сократить до одного выражения не получится. Нет аналога preg_match_all. Без цикла не обойтись.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короче говоря было написано:

```
var parse_expression = "id  INT  (10)  AUTO_INCREMENT  KEY,  \
name  VARCHAR( 255 ),  \
info  VARCHAR    ( 255)  DEFAULT('your text' )  DEFAULT('your text' ) AUTO_INCREMENT, \
text ,   \
age INT(2), \
date DATETIME DEFAULT(NOW()), \
counter INT(10) DEFAULT(10), \
other varchar(255) DEFAULT ('your (mine) text'),\
other2 varchar(255) DEFAULT ('use close braket - ) to finish condition string '),\
other3 varchar(255) DEFAULT ('stop,the split,) ')";

         
var div = document.getElementById('b');

var len = parse_expression.length;
var tokens = [];
var compiler_tokens = {};
var tags = ["'", '"', '(', ')'];
var token = '';
var ifOpenTokens;
        
for(var pos = 0, last_cut = 0; pos < len; pos++, ifOpenTokens = false) {
    if(tags.indexOf(parse_expression[pos]) != -1) {
                
        if(!(parse_expression[pos-1] != undefined 
            && parse_expression[pos-1] == '\\'  // если предыдущий символ - обратный слеш
            && parse_expression[pos-2] != undefined
            && parse_expression[pos-2] != '\\') 
            || parse_expression[pos-1] != '\\'// если предыдущий символ - не слеш, то обрабатываем
        ) {

            if(compiler_tokens[parse_expression[pos]] == undefined || !compiler_tokens[parse_expression[pos]]) {
                if((parse_expression[pos] == '(' || parse_expression[pos] == ')') 
                    && (compiler_tokens['"'] == undefined || !compiler_tokens['"'])  
                    && (compiler_tokens["'"] == undefined || !compiler_tokens["'"])
                ) {
                    compiler_tokens[parse_expression[pos]] = 1;
                }
                else if(parse_expression[pos] == '(' || parse_expression[pos] == ')') {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    compiler_tokens[parse_expression[pos]] = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                if((parse_expression[pos] == '(' || parse_expression[pos] == ')') 
                    && (compiler_tokens['"'] == undefined || !compiler_tokens['"'])
                    && (compiler_tokens["'"] == undefined || !compiler_tokens["'"])
                ) {
                    compiler_tokens[parse_expression[pos]]++;
                }
                else if(parse_expression[pos] == '(' || parse_expression[pos] == ')') {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    compiler_tokens[parse_expression[pos]] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
            
    if(parse_expression[pos] == ',') {
        // check for open tokens
        console.log(compiler_tokens['"'], compiler_tokens['\'']);
        
        if(compiler_tokens['('] != compiler_tokens[')'] 
        && (!compiler_tokens['"'] && !compiler_tokens["'"])) {
            throw new Error("Remained unclosed tags in query '"
                + parse_expression.substring(last_cut, pos));
        }
        else {
            if(compiler_tokens['"'] || compiler_tokens["'"]) {
                ifOpenTokens = true;
            }   
        }
                
        if(!ifOpenTokens) {
            token = parse_expression.substring(last_cut, pos);
            tokens.push(token);
            last_cut += token.length + 1;
        }
    }
            
    if(pos == len - 1) {
        token = parse_expression.substring(last_cut, pos + 1);
        tokens.push(token);
    }
}

if (compiler_tokens['"'] || compiler_tokens["'"]) {
    throw new Error("Remained unclosed tags in query '"+ parse_expression);
}
```

[image]

:D Собака убежала, вроде годно работает. Скрипт также будет разбирать данные в `INSERT`.

Comment: а почему бы не взять просто грамматику sql (например [sql99](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-99.bnf.html)), сократить до разумного размера, и написать годный компилятор?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov так решение уже есть!:D

Comment: да, я вижу. ну так это же часть и какая-то сильно специфичная. впрочем задача ваша, конечно, вам виднее как лучше и проще.